# Signed hex values behaving differently on C program on Mac and PC

Tags: c, serial-port, hex, arduino, signed

I'm writing a program for the Arduino Esplora that displays acceleration values. I've been successful with transmitting data on my Mac, but when I try to use the same program on a Windows machine, the negative values being transmitted over the serial connection are garbled and unusable. I've checked the individual bytes of the data being transmitted and I have confirmed that it is the same on both machines. But then, why are they seeing it as two different values?

```
Value being transmitted = FFFFFF4d 
Actual value, as displayed on Mac = -179
Value being displayed on Windows = -32768
```

Thanks!

Comment: The Windows value is the same as the minimum value of a signed 16 bit value (0xffff). The other value (-179) is the same as the signed decimal version of 0xff4d. To me it smells byte order problems.

Comment: Have you checked that the sizes of the types that you're using are the same on both machines?

Comment: How are you converting the hex string?  Using Convert.ToInt32 in C# produces the same value as the Mac.

Comment: Can you give us the source code of what you're trying to implement for both systems? And are you transmitting the values through string representation from the Arduino, or as an int?

Comment: N.B.: to answer the questions we ask you (so we can better help you) you need to edit your own question and add the additional informations in its text.